# How to implement an OAEP for RSA encryption in Objective C++

Tags: c++, objective-c, encryption, rsa

So basically I made an RSA encryption in xCode using Objective C++ and would like to add a padding now like I saw here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimal_asymmetric_encryption_padding . If that is a bad idea, or there are better options, please tell me, I am a complete beginner, and am just doing this for fun. But anyway, I am not too sure how to go about this, so any help or suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: What have you tried? Have you read through RFC 2437 and/or the current version of PKCS #1?

Comment: I have not no, Im a very beginner haha, but thankyou! so I should do that then?

Comment: That's certainly where I'd start, anyway.